# If/Testing the existence of certain numerous files

Tags: files, regular-expression, directory

In bash, I have a directory that holds some file names that start with underscore `_` and others that don't.

I want my script to check if a folder has any files that don't start with `_`. I write

```
if [[ -f $dir/[!_]* ]]
  then echo "There are unmarked files."
  else echo "All files marked."
fi
```

But when I run using a folder with files that do and do not start with `_`, the `if` statement has the opposite effect of what I intended. I list the entries in the folder that clearly display files without `_`, but the output keeps saying, `All files marked.`

What am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

```sh
if find -not -name '_*' -exec false {} +
then
  echo 'all files marked'
else
  echo 'unmarked file found'
fi
```

Comment: @muru `{} ';'` is not the same as `{} +` - perhaps you could perform an apples for apples test before commenting further - thanks